# If I call an API using XMLhttprequest, it works fine. But when I use angularjs (1.5.6), I get CORS error

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, xmlhttprequest

First of all, I have whitelisted my localhost port 3000 for Cross-Origin requests. I am building a MEAN stack application. And I am trying to consume an API using $http service.

```
myApp.controller('minuteController', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.submitButton = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://url.example.com/server/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=username&password=pass1234&origin=local',
        headers: {'Authorization':'Basic asdsadsads=','Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept':'application/json, text/plain,*/*'}
    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.dataDisplay = response.data;
        console.log(dataDisplay);
    });
}
});
```

If I use the same details to make an XMLHttpRequest it works fine. Below is the code that works.

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://url.example.com/server/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=username&password=pass1234&origin=local";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(myObject);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Accept","application/json, text/plain, */*");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Authorization","Basic asdsadsads=");
xmlhttp.send();
```

[image: errors I see in my console]

[image: Working HTTP request]

[image: Not Working HTTP request]

Comment: Are you sending the requests from the same domain?

Comment: No, I am sending my request from my localhost at port 3000. My API service is on another server and I have whitelisted my localhost port 3000 in there. And like I said,  i don't have any error if call using Javascript XML HTTP request.

Comment: Note that setting the "Access-Control-*" headers on the request is not needed; those need to be on the response from the server.

Comment: I was just trying it out. But removing it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Then send a request with both and find what the differences are. The server-side does not know whether the request was sent via angular or not. It just sees the request, so, since you have told us you are sending both requests from the same place, they must be different somehow. That difference is key to build up a solution in your case.

Comment: You set `withCredentials: true` in AngularJS but don't do that in the XHR. You use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in AngularJS but use `Content-Type: application/json` in the XHR. This is comparing apples to oranges. Make the two identical.

Comment: Getting the same error when sever is not allow access Cross-Origin  or server is not reachable (404), or you missing token authorization (403) try inspect it more

Comment: I have made the request identical now. Still no difference. Same errors in the console.

Comment: Can you take a look at the network tab of the console and see what is in the request and response subtab respectively? There must be a difference if you send the request from the very same domain.

Comment: Added more info on how it looks in my network tab for both requests.

Comment: The second (failed) request is missing a `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem. It's solved my problem by adding `data: ''` in the argument to `$http.`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two requests is that the unsuccessful request is missing

> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

and not specifying that you intend to work with JSON might work differently than you expect.

Comment: changed my content-type value to application/json;charset=UTF-8. I can still see the same error.

And for some reason, I cant see content-type value in the request headers in my networks tab of developer tools.

Comment: @Ashish308 then it is not being sent. This must be the problem.

Comment: @Ashish308 I see you have found the solution. I will keep my answer here, as it might be the solution for other problems though.